# What is the preferred technique to convert an object's properties to a sorted list of tuples?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm working with an open-source library and they define a class like so:

```
class Provider(object):
    """ Defines for each of the supported providers """
    DUMMY = 0
    EC2 = 1
    EC2_EU = 2
    RACKSPACE = 3
    SLICEHOST = 4
    GOGRID = 5
    VPSNET = 6
    LINODE = 7
    VCLOUD = 8
    RIMUHOSTING = 9
```

I need to take the properties (DUMMY, EC2, etc.) and convert them to a sorted list of tuples that would look something like this:

```
[(0, 'DUMMY'), (1, 'EC2'), ...]
```

I want to sort on the name of the property itself. I've come up with a few ways to tackle this, including the following which seems like an inefficient way to handle this:

```
import operator
from libcloud.types import Provider

PROVIDER_CHOICES = [(v,k) for k, v in vars(Provider).items()
                                   if not k.startswith('__')]
PROVIDER_CHOICES = sorted(PROVIDER_CHOICES, key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

It works but seems inelegant and like there may be a better way. I also see flaws in the way I'm constructing the list by doing the `if not k.startswith('__')` - mainly what if the open-source lib adds methods to the Provider class?

Just looking for some opinions and other techniques that may work better for this.

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Use `if not k.startswith('_')`. It is a convention that items that start with '_' are not public.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? If you want to have a container for constants, you might as well use a dictionary instead. Or just use the strings (e.g. 'GOGRID'), since that's the pythonic way of dealing with such things. (Strings are interned, and having many of the same string does not hit memory - thus they are somehow similar to lisp symbols.)

Comment: @Randell, @bayer I need to supply a list of 2-tuples as an argument for a model in Django: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#choices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for class variables that are of the type integer, you could do it like this:

```
import inspect
PROVIDER_CHOICES = inspect.getmembers(Foo, lambda x: isinstance(x, int))
```

Check out the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module for more information.

---

As an aside: you can use `PROVIDER_CHOICES.sort(key=...)` in your last line, which does an inplace sort.

Edit: `getmembers` returns a sorted list as stated in the documentation so `sorted` is unnecessary (thanks J.F. Sebastian)

Comment: this is great. much more elegant and easier to understand. J.F. is right I removed the `sorted()` wrapped around `inspect.getmembers()` and it sorted perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about methods and other types of attributes just filter them out too.

```
PROVIDER_CHOICES = [(v,k) for k, v in vars(Provider).iteritems()
                          if not k.startswith('_') and isinstance(v,int)]
PROVIDER_CHOICES.sort( key=itemgetter(1) )
```

You just have to run this once for every class in question, so speed shouldn't be a issue to begin with. If you really care, you can just store the list on the class itself.